# Composing a Gmail filter: "on this list and not to me"?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I filter all mail received from the mail list ***mylist*** with this filter and label it for later reading:

```
Matches: list:(<mylist.example.com>)
```

I would like to modify this for this logic:

```
if the mailing list is <mylist.example.com>
AND if I am not a direct recipient
```

The intention being that "general" mail list traffic is labelled, but replies to the list *and myself* stay in my inbox.

How can I express this in a Gmail filter rule?

Comment: I, too, am curious about this exact filter. Any luck?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would expect that

```
{list:mylist1 list:mylist2} -to:myname@example.com
```

would do what you want. The `-` indicates a negative match, so should match messages from either of the lists where your email address does not appear in the `to:` field.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution thanks to the responses. More specifically, I wanted to filter messages from a Google group. I got to this one (hope it works for other people as well):

```
to:(mygroup@googlegroups.com -mymail@gmail.com)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 {list:mylist1 list:mylist2} to:myname@example.com is:unread
```

This rule will find messages:

- from mylist1 or mylist2
- to myname@example.com
- that have not been read